# Using setScale in BigDecimal

Tags: java, bigdecimal

Can anyone helpme out with BigDecimal, I'm a newbie in it
I want to round of 24.33 to 25.00
I just need to perform ceiling operation
so I did something like this

```
BigDecimal amount = new BigDecimal("24.33");
System.out.println(amount.setScale(2, RoundingMode.CEILING));
```

I was expecting to get 25.00 but I'm still getting 24.33
any idea's where am i going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The scale applies to the part after the decimal point. What you want is:

```
BigDecimal amount = new BigDecimal("24.33");
System.out.println(amount.setScale(0, RoundingMode.CEILING));
```

Also remember `BigDecimal`s are [Immutable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable_object), and so all operations return a new BigDecimal representing the result of the operation. Can catch you out if you're not used to it.

Comment: I needed the result to be 25.00, but I was getting 25, so I added setScale(2) to the result amount.setScale(0, RoundingMode.CEILING).setScale(2) , is this ok to do?

Comment: Yes, it results in a new BigDecimal instance but it is acceptable. You can also use a `DecimalFormat` instance if you have a requirement to always show a certain number of decimal places, but then you have to convert to a `double` primitve which can result in a loss of accuracy.

Comment: You don't need to convert to a double. DecimalFormat happily accepts BigDecimals via the `format(Object)` method.

Answer (score 2):

Try this -

```
BigDecimal amount = new BigDecimal("24.33");  
System.out.println(amount.setScale(0, RoundingMode.CEILING).setScale(2));
```

The extra `setScale(2)` is to get 25.00 as you desired, without the extra `setScale` you will get 25 as the answer.